# Can I use a Vue interpolation inside a VuePress code block

Tags: vuepress, vuepress2

In my VuePress project I have a code block that looks like this

````cs
```cs
   string pageName = getPageName("{{ $page.key }}");
```
````

What I want to see on the static site is:

````cs
```cs
   string pageName = getPageName("v-10013ae8");
```
````

Where the interpolation of `{{ $page.key }}` is rendered as `v-10013ae8`

I've tried

- `~~~{{ $page.key }}~~~`
- ````` ````{{ $page.key }}```` `````

This is the VuePress documentation I have been following

- [Templating/Interpolation](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#interpolation)
- [Syntax Highlighting](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown.html#syntax-highlighting-in-code-blocks)